# get the name of control which got modified in FormGroup or FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want get the name of control, which got modified over form in UI.

I have a use case where i need the name of form control dynamically when any control is updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it a good solution but it can solve your problem I think. Also you can check console on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcwedv)

*on your component.ts*

```
  form: FormGroup;
  modified: Array<{ formControlName: string, controls: AbstractControl }> = [];
  clickCount = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      input1: new FormControl(''),
      input2: new FormControl(''),
      input3: new FormControl(''),
      input4: new FormControl(''),
      input5: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.getChanged());

  }

  setValue(){
    this.form.get(`input${this.clickCount}`).setValue("not modified by UI");
    this.clickCount++;
    if(this.clickCount == 6) this.clickCount = 1;
  }

  getChanged() {
    let controlKeys = Object.keys(this.form.controls);

    controlKeys.forEach(key => {
      let control = this.form.get(key);
      if (control.dirty) {
        let idx = this.modified.findIndex(x => x.formControlName == key);
        if (idx == -1) {
          this.modified.push({ formControlName: key, controls: control });
        }
        else {
          this.modified.slice(idx, 1);
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(this.modified);
  }
```

*on your component.html*

```
<input formControlName="input1" type="text"/>
<input formControlName="input2" type="text"/>
<input formControlName="input3" type="text"/>
<input formControlName="input4" type="text"/>
<input formControlName="input5" type="text"/>
```

Comment: it's way too long code just to get the control name, i have found a workaround to use event emitters.